# Is there a way to supress "Name Conflicts" dialog before opening XLSX file by C# in Excel 2007?

Tags: c#, excel, popup, worksheet

I am facing a problem while opening xlsx workbook by C# code.

Problem:
         A pop appear while opening the xlsx, and user expected to acknowledge it.

Reason:
         Reason of pop is known since this this is known problem.

Probable Solution: Needs to automate and suppress this pop up so no manual intervention is needed.

Reference of one such solution in VB:
          http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/546c7506-7146-45b6-873e-b3793df2979b/is-there-a-way-to-supress-name-conflicts-dialog-in-excel-2007?forum=exceldev

**Question to Forum:**

Solution mentioned above is VB based. I am in search of such solution in C#.** And importantly **query is how to detect such pop up within code.

Pop up is seen after invoking:  Workbook.Open(.....).
Also it is neither exception nor there is return value.

Is there any way to find out such pop in advance before opening file?

Answer (score 0):

the link shows you not VB.NET code, its VBA code.
For this code you must allready open the XLSX document.

But i know no way to find it before you open the document.

One way, not a good way. To look into the xlsx file (its a zip archive) and find the place and remove it. You can try to use the OpenXML SDK from Microsoft to remove the defined name.

Here you find the description of OpenXML SDK for Excel:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet(v=office.15).aspx

I hope it helps a little!

Comment: Hello Andreas, Is there way to detect this pop up after opening the file and fill data and "Ok" by C# code itself. Now user has to look for pop up and enter some data (rename filterdatabse), then pop up disappear. Irrespective of suppressing pop up, dealing pop up automatically will also be good. Unlike VBA code( Trap error), I am not able to find how C# can sense this pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in a workbook which is getting filled dynamicaly via C# and filters some data.

After i executed this VBA code:

```
On Error Resume Next
With Workbook("YourWokrbookName")
  .Names("_FilterDatabase").Delete
  .Names("Criteria").Delete
  .Names("Extract").Delete
End With
On Error GoTo 0
```

Which i found [here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/clearing_the_advanced_filter_dialog_box/) and adapted for my use i never got the naming confict messagebox again. 
The simply deletes the _FilterDatabase object in the worksheet. This might be not usefull in every case but in my case it didn't made a difference.